# Excel macro / script to cut/paste text between columns

Tags: vba, excel, csv, macros

I am working in as a business developer, however the problems in our support department sometimes require me to work on clients' CSV file i.e. Excel spreadsheet containing product catalog.

Right now I have an Export CSV from an online store, where the first column is formatted in the following way:

Name_of_the_product - {store category)

e.g. Sony NEX-6 - {digital camera}

I need a macro/script to take cut the words between {} and paste it into the column immediately to the right, without the {}. This way I will have clean product name i.e. Sony NEX-6, as well as the store category for each product e.g. digital camera (which I need to push the product feed via a third party solution).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Tim! I have posted the answer below - since the CSV feed had over 550 rows I needed to fin a way to automate it. I seem to have figured it out mostly. Sorry if the question was no detailed enough, I never had the need to work using Excel macros, but now I see how powerful they are. I will brush up my knowledge asap!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data in column A. And have 100 rows.

```
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim text_string As String
    Dim LeftSide As String
    Dim RightSide As String

    For i = 1 To 100
       text_string = Range("A" & i).Value
       WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "{")
       LeftSide = WrdArray(LBound(WrdArray))
       RightSide = WrdArray(UBound(WrdArray))
       Range("A" & i).Value = LeftSide
       Range("B" & i).Value = Replace(Result, "}", "")
    Next i
```

And if you want to understand the split function, you can refer this blog post.
http://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2015/06/split-function.html

Comment: Thank you! Almost got it to work, however there are two things.

Comment: Except of cutting what is within the {} it takes everything else and puts it in the new column; that is not necessarily a problem (i can always flip the two columns), but i need to have this information cut from the original columns.

Comment: Please check the code now. I did slight modification to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it mostly working using the following function:

=MID(A2;FIND("[";A2)+1;FIND("]";A2) - FIND("[";A2) - 1)

The only thing now left to do is to delete what was copied from the A column (including the []) - does anyone have the idea for the macro? I hope I can get it working using a Search/Replace functionality from a feed management solution, but I am checking with our support for that.

Thank you all!